# Use jquery submodule?

Tags: jquery, webpack, vuejs3

There is a Vue application and there is a separate bundle with all the UI logic in jquery.
I'm trying to use that bundle as a submodule for my Vue application.
Initially, I just used some bundle modules in my application, installing jquery packages in a vue application.

Now it is designed as a submodule, and I have two jquery variants generated, one with all the plugins from the submodule and an empty one from vue that are passed through ProvidePlugin

This is how I connect jquery

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
```

How to correctly use webpack packages of a submodule (Vue sees them and collects what is used) and how to forward the jquery submodule through the provide plugin

This bundle saved a lot of time and I won’t give it up

Comment: Using jQuery inside Cue is a code smell... why do you need to have two frameworks?

Comment: The old ui was written using bundle jquery. There is no need to rewrite it in Vue yet.